# Turn float object into tuple

Tags: python

```
def get_day_month_year(date):
    d, m, y = date.split(',')# split the date and return a tuple of integer (day, month, year)

    return (d, m, y)

print(get_day_month_year(1/11/1970))
```

I am not able to get `(1,11,1970)` instead i get an error. May I know what's wrong??

Comment: Your string separator is "/" while you are splitting using ","

Comment: What's the error? Your input is not a string, and can't be used with `split`.

Comment: `1/11/1970` is not a string, for one, it is an expression that resolves into an int (0, btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_day_month_year(date):
    d, m, y = date.split('/')
    return (d, m, y)

print(get_day_month_year("1/11/1970"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. `1/11/1970` is a number (1 divided by 11 divided by 1970), you're looking for a string (`"1/11/1970"`).
2. The function splits on commas, you probably want it to split on `"/"` instead of `","`.